# Left aligning number of Un ordered List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I am playing around with UN-ordered list in HTML and was wondering if following display is possible on dynamically generated `ul`s.

```
*    Hello
*        Hi
*        Bi
*    Name
*        Ron
*        Mat
*    Cloth
*        Color
*            Red
```

So i start with appending `UL` to `DIV` with jquery `append` function and keep adding depending upon the tree scope, but result i am getting is -

```
    *Hello
        *Hi
        *Bi
    *Name
        *Ron
        *Mat
    *Cloth
        *Color
            *Red
```

Is there a way to align stars to the left via CSS?

Comment: Not a fancy solution but you could have them at same level instead of nesting and with indent `&emsp;` https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/jougr6cz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `position:relative/absolute` along with `::before`

```css
.ul {
  position: relative;
}
li {
  list-style: none
}
li::before {
  content: "*";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li>Hello
    <ul>
      <li>li</li>
      <li>bi</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Name
    <ul>
      <li>Ron</li>
      <li>Mat</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Cloth
    <ul>
      <li>Color
        <ul>
          <li>Red</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: there is no li, these all elements are ul's. Will this solution be valid for ul only?

Comment: I'm not at the computer right now so I can't update my answer but yes it will be valid. Just remember you can't have an ul as direct child of another ul. You must use li like I'm using.

Comment: My Bad i thought i selected yours as answer, both are correct answers though

Answer (score 1):

You use pseudo elements positioned absolutely in place of the standard bullet points. I used the unicode character of bullet point \u2022 but you can use whatever would like. Here is an example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/t65krsou/

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
}

#mainList{
  position: relative;
}


li:before{
  content: "\2022";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mainList">
  <li>
  hi
  <ul>
    <li>hi again</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  sup
    <ul>
      <li>yo</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  another!
    <ul>
      <li>I can do this</li>
      <li>all day!
      <ul>
        <li>see?</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

Comment: there is no li, these all elements are ul's. Will this solution be valid for ul only?